# Concurrent database (PostgreSQL) commands in the same transaction

Tags: .net, multithreading, postgresql, transactions, thread-safety

I'm writing a .NET 4 application that imports a large amount of data from a file into a PostgreSQL 9.1 database. Profiling shows that the DB calls to actually INSERT the data take up over 90% of the time. The DB server appears to be CPU-bound - using all of one CPU.

If possible, I'd like to import the data faster by using all the CPUs. The input file could be broken up into pieces on the client, so this normally wouldn't be too hard, but I want to ensure that if any errors occur in importing a file then the DB is not modified at all. To accomplish this I'm doing the entire import in one transaction.

Is it possible to somehow send concurrent commands to the DB server (to utilise all of its CPUs), but still ensure that either the entire import succeeds or no changes are made? As far as I understand a transaction cannot be used from multiple threads to run multiple commands concurrently, can it? I'm using Npgsql as the ADO.NET provider, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

A transaction cannot be processed in parallel by multiple threads with standard PostgreSQL before **Postgres 9.6**, where this feature was added as [**"parallel query"**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-query.html).

It seems suspicious, though, that your INSERT operation is CPU-bound. A couple of things might be improved here. How exactly do you send the data to the server? There are basically four ways to `INSERT` data into a table:

1. one row at a time with a `VALUES` expression providing literals
2. multiple rows at a time a `VALUES` expression
3. [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) with `SELECT` (inserting 0-n rows)
4. [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

`COPY` is the fastest method by far.

- It is faster to **delete indexes** before a huge bulk `INSERT` / `COPY` and recreate them afterwards. Incrementally adding index tuples is much less efficient than creating an index at once.
- **Triggers, constraints or foreign key constraints** are other factors that can slow you down. Maybe you could disable / delete before the bulk load and enable / recreate afterwards?

There are also a number of settings that can make a substantial difference.

- You could turn off [**fsync** and **synchronous_commit**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html). (Risky!)
- Disable `autovacuum` temporarily. Run `ANALYZE` immediately afterwards. (Careful with those!)

Read the article about [Bulk Loading and Restores](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Bulk_Loading_and_Restores) and [Tuning Your PostgreSQL Server](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) in the Postgres Wiki, especially the paragraphs on **checkpoint_segments** and **checkpoint_completion_target**.

The operation may not be as CPU-bound as it seems. Have a look at this [paragraph in the PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Priorities#Is_CPU_really_the_bottleneck.3F).

One more source of slowdown might be logging. For instance, [`log_statement = all`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html) produces huge log files, at a cost, especially with single-row inserts.

Here is a [quick method to check all your custom settings](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Server_Configuration) in the PostgreSQL Wiki once more.

One more idea to speed up things, especially as you cannot turn off fsync. Create one or more empty **temporary tables** like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE x_tmp AS SELECT * FROM real_tbl LIMIT 0;
```

Put some thought into how to deal with sequences and other defaults!
`INSERT` all data into the staging table(s), then write to target tables in one command. Indexes and constraints off again, but for a much shorter time.

```
INSERT INTO real_tbl SELECT * FROM x_tmp ORDER BY something;
DROP TABLE x_tmp;
```

Could be substantially faster. Be sure to use enough RAM for various settings. Look at [`temp_buffers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/currentruntime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY) in particular.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Erwin. I'm inserting one row at a time, because I often need the auto-generated ID of the new row to insert other rows that depend on it. I know it's possible to use `WITH` to insert several dependent rows in one go - that's something I still have to try. I don't see any way I could use `COPY` or `INSERT` by `SELECT` here, but I'll try out your idea of deleting indexes and disabling constraints and autovacuum beforehand. There are also triggers in the DB, but only `ON DELETE` ones, so I'm guessing they shouldn't slow down `INSERT`.

Comment: I don't think I could turn off `fsync` as I don't own the DB server. Turning off `synchronous_commit` just for my DB might be possible, but since there's only one COMMIT at the end I'm guessing it wouldn't make much of a difference (the COMMIT itself is fast).

Comment: Single row INSERTs are the slowest method by far. Maybe you can do some preprocessing and insert at least several rows at a time? CTEs (WITH clause) are a nice feature, but they will give you nothing you couldn't do with a subselect also. The DELETE triggers shouldn't be relevant. `synchronous_commit` won't help much with a single transaction, `fsync` *would* certainly help, but it is risky to tamper with anyway. I'll amend my answer with one more idea ...

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try disabling constraints first and see how much that helps, then see if there's a way to make the temp tables work. I suspect it would be difficult because of the dependencies between tables and the auto-generated IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Another plan of actions might be this:

- Define a new, *not normalized* table holding your input data. Let's call it "staging"
- Fill that table using multiple threads and multiple connections.
- Once the data is there, insert the required IDs using the sequence from the *real* tables into the staging table.
- The parallel working phase ends here.
- Use one transaction and perform the appropriate bulk insert statements moving your data from the staging table into the real tables.
- Truncate the staging table.

In this scenario your current bottleneck (CPU bound due to input processing) is relieved by paying more IO coins.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't think it would be practical with a DB of this complexity (it has over 200 tables with lots of dependencies between tables). It's certainly something I'll keep in mind for other (simpler) import tasks, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should use [prepared transactions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-prepare-transaction.html).  Run as many in parallel as you want, and if they all get to the stage they can be prepared without error, then commit prepared them otherwise rollback prepared them.

You first have to set max_prepared_transactions to some value above 0 and restart postgresql.  After that, you start a transaction in a single session like so:

```
begin; 
select yada; 
insert yada; 
update yada; 
prepare transaction 'mytrans';
```

at which point you will receive either the notice "PREPARE TRANSACTION" or "ROLLBACK".  If you get ROLLBACK from any of your prepared transactions then you can do a rollback prepared on each of your transactions and none go through.  Note that you should not leave lots of prepared transactions hanging around.

Comment: That's a possibility, but I think it would only work for tables that are independent of anything else. Eg. if table B references table A then I can't insert those in separate prepared transactions, because any row in B could potentially reference any row in A - I have no way to parition them "vertically" before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that pg_restore is now using a several-threads mode to get benefits from multicore architecture in restoring compress dumps. So managing heavy imports on several connexions is certainly a good idea. I have seen reports of nice gains with setting the number of jobs to 2*number of core for pg_restore.

But pg_restore cannot use `--single-transaction` with this setting. So the same problem as you. You may try **2-phase commit transactions** with [PREPARE TRANSACTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare-transaction.html) statements, it's usually something done by transaction managers, not applications, but this could help you invalidate several transactions if one of them fail in your import process.